# Pass context with Hilt from ViewModel to data source

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger, dagger-hilt

I'm trying to use Hilt to pass context along to my data source class, below:

```
public class PostDataSource extends PageKeyedDataSource<Integer, Post> {

    // we will start from the first page which is 1
    public static final int PAGE_SIZE = 25;

    // we will start from the first page which is 1
    private static final int FIRST_PAGE = 1;

    // this will be called once to load the initial data
    @Override
    public void loadInitial(@NonNull LoadInitialParams<Integer> params, @NonNull final LoadInitialCallback<Integer, Post> callback) {
        // I NEED TO CALL CONTEXT HERE

    }
}
```

`PostDataSource` has a data source factory:

```
public class PostDataSourceFactory extends DataSource.Factory {

    //creating the mutable live data
    private MutableLiveData<PageKeyedDataSource<Integer, Post>> itemLiveDataSource = new MutableLiveData<>();

    @Override
    public DataSource<Integer, Post> create() {
        //getting our data source object
        PostDataSource postDataSource = new PostDataSource();

        //posting the datasource to get the values
        itemLiveDataSource.postValue(postDataSource);

        //returning the datasource
        return postDataSource;
    }


    //getter for itemlivedatasource
    public MutableLiveData<PageKeyedDataSource<Integer, Post>> getItemLiveDataSource() {
        return itemLiveDataSource;
    }
}
```

And finally, here is the ViewModel class. This ViewModel is called from my fragment:

```
public class PostViewModel extends ViewModel {

    //creating livedata for PagedList  and PagedKeyedDataSource
    public LiveData<PagedList<Post>> itemPagedList;
    LiveData<PageKeyedDataSource<Integer, Post>> liveDataSource;

    //constructor
    public PostViewModel() {
        //getting our data source factory
        PostDataSourceFactory postDataSourceFactory = new PostDataSourceFactory();

        //getting the live data source from data source factory
        liveDataSource = postDataSourceFactory.getItemLiveDataSource();

        //Getting PagedList config
        PagedList.Config pagedListConfig =
                (new PagedList.Config.Builder())
                        .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
                        .setPageSize(PostDataSource.PAGE_SIZE).build();

        //Building the paged list
        itemPagedList = (new LivePagedListBuilder(postDataSourceFactory, pagedListConfig))
                .build();
    }
}
```

I don't understand how I would get context in `PostDataSource` using Hilt's dependency injection.

I've tried doing something like this, but not really sure how to proceed:

```
public class PostDataSource extends PageKeyedDataSource<Integer, Post> {

    private Context context;

    @Inject
    PostDataSource(@ActivityContext Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind DI is to avoid having object creation in your code. You may want to inject `PostDataSourceFactory` as well.

`Context` in your `PostDataSource` will be injected from the generated modules in `ActivityComponent` or `FragmentComponent`. This comes out of box for Hilt.

You need to annotate the constructor of your factory so you can use `Provider<>` to create your source, instead of doing it manually:

```
public class PostDataSourceFactory extends DataSource.Factory {
    private Provider<PostDataSource> mSourceProvider;
    
    @Inject
    public PostDataSourceFactory(Provider<PostDataSource> sourceProvider){
        mSourceProvider = sourceProvider
    }

    //creating the mutable live data
    private MutableLiveData<PageKeyedDataSource<Integer, Post>> itemLiveDataSource = new MutableLiveData<>();

    @Override
    public DataSource<Integer, Post> create() {
        //getting our data source object
        PostDataSource postDataSource = mSourceProvider.get()

        //posting the datasource to get the values
        itemLiveDataSource.postValue(postDataSource);

        //returning the datasource
        return postDataSource;
    }


    //getter for itemlivedatasource
    public MutableLiveData<PageKeyedDataSource<Integer, Post>> getItemLiveDataSource() {
        return itemLiveDataSource;
    }
}
```

You also need to inject `PostDataSource` constructor.

Comment: The following line in `PostViewModel` now requires parameters though, no? `PostDataSourceFactory postDataSourceFactory = new PostDataSourceFactory();`

Comment: That factory should be injected in the viewmodel.

Comment: I tried doing this but no luck:

`@AndroidEntryPoint
public class PostViewModel extends ViewModel {

    //creating livedata for PagedList  and PagedKeyedDataSource
    public LiveData<PagedList<Post>> itemPagedList;
    LiveData<PageKeyedDataSource<Integer, Post>> liveDataSource;

    @Inject
    private PostDataSourceFactory postDataSourceFactory;

    @Inject
    public PostViewModel() {
        //getting our data source factory
        postDataSourceFactory = new PostDataSourceFactory();
    }
}`

Still requires a parameter